# Cloud Run Memory Restriction

Tags: google-cloud-platform, serverless, google-cloud-run

How do I get a Cloud Run container that uses more than 2 GB run on custom GKE cluster?

Since Cloud Run uses knative, I wonder if it is possible to tweak deployment describtor with more allocated/allowed memory limit to run it on GKE.

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1alpha1
kind: Revision
metadata:
 ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I get a Cloud Run container that uses more than 2 GB run on
> custom GKE cluster?

The maximum memory that you can allocate to a container in Cloud Run Managed is 2 GB.

[UPDATE 2]

Cloud Run now supports 32 GB, but the larger memory features are in preview. This document provides details on memory limits.

[Set and update memory limits](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/memory-limits#setting)

[UPDATE]

- Cloud Run Managed now supports 8 GB. [Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/release-notes#December_18_2020).

For Cloud Run on Kubernetes, you can request more memory:

```
gcloud beta run deploy --image gcr.io/cloudrun/hello --memory=4G --cluster ha-cluster-1
```

> Since Cloud Run uses knative, I wonder if it is possible to tweak
> deployment describtor with more allocated/allowed memory limit to run
> it on GKE.

Cloud Run Managed does not run in Knative, it runs in gVisor. I wrote an article that describes the Cloud Run infrastructure plus the Knative API that both Cloud Run Managed and Cloud Run on Kubernetes expose [here](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-run-deep-dive-understanding-the-apis-part-1/). However, even with direct access to the Cloud Run Knative API, you cannot get around the imposed service limits.

The purpose of Cloud Run is to simplify deployments by abstracting away implementation details of the underlying infrastructure. There are cases where you should deploy directly to Kubernetes.

Comment: Cloud Run (fully managed) now supports 8GB of memory https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas#cloud_run_limits

Comment: @DonnaldCucharo - Thank you. I have updated my answer with a link to the release notes mentioning the increase to 8 GB.

Comment: 16 gibibyte is now available

Comment: Cloud Run now supports 32 GiB of memory
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/memory-limits

Comment: @abdelhadidanba - Thank you. However, larger than 8 GB is in preview at this time. That limits who can access those features.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, when you are using Cloud Run on GKE, you're using Knative serving stack, which allows you to configure custom CPU and memory requests/limits just like Kubernetes: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/

For example, to get 4 GiB memory, you must add a field like:

```
resources:
  limits:
    memory: "4GiB"
```

to your `container:` field in Knative `Service` spec.

In Knative 0.6 (serving v1beta1) this field's path would be `Service.spec.template.spec.containers[*].resources` field, in earlier versions (serving v1alpha1) something like `Service.spec.runLatest.revisionTemplate.spec.container.resources`.